# How to css divi hover effect

Tags: css, wordpress

I am setting up a new website, and I want to add a CSS hover effect. Can you tell me what to do? I want my image has a zoom hover effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.zoom {
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: transform .2s;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.zoom:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(1.5); 
}
```

```html
<h1>Zoom on Hover</h1>
<p>Hover over the div element.</p>
<div class="zoom"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" ></div>
```